# Sharing environment variables across languages

Tags: c#, c++, windows, environment-variables

I'm writing an application composed by several modules written in different languages (i.e. Java, C#, C++).
I'm experiencing an odd behavior where the environment variables that I set in one module (e.g. C#) are not propagated to other modules.
As far as I understand, the problem is due to the fact that environment variables in Windows are accessed via the _environ struct in the runtime library, rather than via the process descriptor, hence libraries using different runtimes have different environment variables.

For C# in particular, this problem seems to occur only if I compile and run the code in Release, whereas compiling the code in Debug works just fine.

The code below reproduce the issue with two very simple modules written in C# and C++. I compiled the code with VS2015 Professional. C# code was compiled with runtime v4.0 and .NET framework v4.5.2

C# executable

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("cpp_lib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern void print_path();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
            path += ";D:\\Temp";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path);
            // Print the path from C#
            Console.WriteLine("Path from C#: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"));
            // Print the path from c++
            print_path();
        }
    }
}
```

C++ library

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" {

  __declspec(dllexport) void print_path() {
    std::cout << "PATH seen in C++: " << getenv("PATH") << std::endl;
  }

}
```

As stated before, running the code in Debug the same path is printed from C# and C++, but running the code in Release results in the PATH printed from c++ missing the D:\Temp folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Windows provide more functions to get environment variables.
From the documentation *"getenv and _putenv use the copy of the environment pointed to by the global variable _environ to access the environment."* whereas GetEnvironmentVariable *"Retrieves the contents of the specified variable from the environment block of the calling process."*
From these statements GetEnvironmentVariable looks like the safest alternative and replacing getenv with GetEnvironmentVariable indeed resolve the problem.

References:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c27a6623-6f57-4c7e-be9b-6dd35d362872/sharing-environment-variables-across-languages?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable

Answer (score 1):

User Environment variables are per-process and changes are not propagated to other processes.

To change system environment variables in your example `PATH`.  You need to modify the value under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and then broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.  Applications wishing to see the change will have to handle the broadcast.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables

Comment: What makes you think there are multiple processes involved?

Comment: This is a single process application. The C# application imports the C++ dll. Both live in the same process

Comment: @MarcoGiglio sorry about that. I think this still applies though: _"...Calling SetEnvironmentVariable has no effect on the system environment variables...."_

Comment: As a matter of fact, we're changing the process environment variables. Of course this does not affect other processes nor the system.